# Frontend view of normal Visitor

Tags: user-roles, front-end

Is there a way to see the frontend from the perspective of a normal visitor? Perhaps a plugin or a way to disable the user_role check (don´t know how it works) only in the frontend without beeing logged-out automaticly.

I´m logged-in as a admin and want

- not to see the edit post links
- not to see the admin bar
- to see the normal comment form
- to see the normal checkboxes from plugins (subscribe to comments, posts) under comments
- few other things that are different

I don´t want to use different browsers while editing a WordPress Website.

Answer (score 0):

When you use chrome, you can open an incognito tab and view the website without being logged in (or logged in as another user) while staying logged in in your other 'non-incognito' tab.

With firefox: open a private window (using private browsing)

With internet explorer:  Use InPrivate-navigation